# Improve sql code performance for a mariaDB query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I developed an application connected to mariaDB (Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.31-MariaDB, for Win32) in DelphiXE8.
I want to improve query performance.
Describe the simplified scenario:

de_User      Table (innoDB)     (rows 81762)

```
ID_U   INT PRIMARY KEY
Name   VARCHAR(30)
INDEX ID_U,  Name
```

de_doc     Table (innoDB)   (rows 260452)

```
IDD   INT PRIMARY KEY
DataFi  Date
UserID  INT
...
INDEX IDD, UserID, DataFi
----
CONSTRAINT UserID_LK
FOREIGN KEY de_Doc  (UserID)
REFERENCES  de_User (ID_U)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

my query

```
select User.*, Doc.LastDoc
FROM de_Users AS Us 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT UserID,MAX(DataFi) AS LastDoc
FROM de_doc 
GROUP BY UserID
) as Doc on Doc.UserID = Us.ID_U

ORDER BY Us.Name ASC, Doc.LastDoc DESC;
```

--
EXPLAIN  select ...

```
+------+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+----------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table          | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref            | rows   | Extra                           |
+------+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+----------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | de_User        | ALL   | NULL          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL           |  81762 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>     | ref   | key0          | key0     | 5       | Base.Us.ID_U   |     10 |                                 |
|    2 | DERIVED     | de_Doc         | index | NULL          | UserID_LK| 4       | NULL           | 260452 |                                 |
+------+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+----------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

my.ini
...

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
...
key_buffer = 4096M
key_buffer_size=1024M
table_open_cache = 2048
query_cache_size = 128M
max_connections = 100
...
max_allowed_packet = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 4096M
net_buffer_length = 16M
read_buffer_size = 256M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 256M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
...
# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M
# DEPRECATED innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 1024M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 128M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
...
thread_concurrency = 4
...
[isamchk]
key_buffer = 1024M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 8M
write_buffer = 16M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 1024M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 8M
write_buffer = 8M
```

TEST phpmyadmin:

```
83705 total, the query employed 1,0000 sec.
if I remove "order by Doc.LastDoc DESC" it is very fast
83705 total, the query employed 0,0000 sec.
```

TEST in my application developed with delphiEX8

```
view table all rows 2,8 sec.
if I remove "order by Doc.LastDoc DESC" it is very fast
view table all rows 1,8 sec.
```

How can I improve performance?

Comment: Do you have an index in table `de_documents ` as `INDEX UserID` if not add and share the `explain` output

Comment: I do not understand.
my code is much more complex, I wrote synthesized.
I described that I created the indexes on the two tables and the relation.
I wrote the EXPLAIN result and my.ini configuration
I wrote the query to be optimized.

Comment: Yeah i can read your question. So what are you trying to say?

Comment: sorry,  I want to improve query performance.I believe it can be faster.

Comment: that is why i asked is there any index for column `userID`?

Comment: *"sorry, I want to improve query performance.I believe it can be faster. "*  From the question i understand that `ORDER BY Us.Name ASC, Doc.LastDoc DESC;` is the "critcal" point?  The short answer is you can't directly index it as the `ORDER BY` uses two tables, one workaround is making a ["Materialized view"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) to maintain a table which you can use to sort on indexes -> [Materialized view in MySQL](http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/databases/creating-mysql-materialized-views/)

Comment: How much RAM?  Which Engine?

Comment: When timing, be sure to avoid the Query cache by using `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`.  That is _probably_ the reason for the `0,0000 sec`.

Comment: phpmyadmin _probably_ tacks on a `LIMIT`, thereby changing what the Optimizer will do!

Comment: Please post text results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%used%'; for analysis.  How many CORES on your host CPU?

Comment: @carmelocony Disclaimer: I am the content author of web site mentioned in my profile, Network profile.  After all the extended comments, question/answers, please use contact information to get in touch with me.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions for your my.ini [mysqld] SECTION

```
sort_buffer_size=2M  # from 4096M (4G) of RAM per connection, next 2 are per connect also
read_buffer_size=256K  # from 256M to reduce volume of data retrieved by 99%
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K  # from ? to a reasonable size
```

These three could be dynamically set (as root) with SET GLOBAL variable_name=value replace K with *1024 and M with *1024*1024   for Kbytes and Megabytes, please.  Please post positive/negative results after a full BUSINESS DAY of uptime.

Comment: I made the suggested changes. The performances on the first tests are the same as the previous ones.
I apply the settings suggested by Wilson Hauck. thank you

Comment: @carmelocony Please post AFTER 24 hours of uptime, text results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%used%'; for analysis. How many CORES on your host CPU? Post results of EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (your query); including the QUERY.

Comment: @carmelocony Only new SESSIONS will inherit the modified Global Variable settings.  Try your query with new login to mysql for your timing and 1st execution timing should be ignored, please.

Comment: I got the best results with these:
key_buffer=    2048M
sort_buffer_size =    8M
read_buffer_size =    2M
read_rnd_buffer_size =   16M

innodb_buffer_pool_size =      2048M
innodb_log_file_size =  512M

Comment: @carmelocony Thanks for sharing your settings for best results. When you have time, please post AFTER 24 hours of uptime, text results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%used%'; and B)  SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%open%'; for analysis. How many CORES on your host CPU? Post current results of EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (your query); including the QUERY.

Answer (score 0):

- This is ambiguous:  `INDEX IDD, UserID, DataFi`
- Probably `User.*` was supposed to be `Us.*`?  Be aware that "simplifying" a query may turn it into a different problem.
- Probably `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary; use `JOIN`.
- You need this *composite* `INDEX(UserID, LastDoc)`
- Do you really want 82K rows in the output?  What will the client do with that much data?  I ask because if the client will further digest the results, maybe such would be better done in SQL.
- When timing, be sure to avoid the Query cache by using SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE.
- phpmyadmin probably tacks on a LIMIT, thereby changing what the Optimizer will do!
- `ORDER BY t1.a, t2.b` (different tables) makes it impossible to use an index for ordering.  This will prevent any sort of short-circuiting of the query.

Comment: *Probably LEFT JOIN is unnecessary; use JOIN.
[It is important to view all users]
*You need this composite INDEX(UserID, LastDoc)
[I did]
*Do you really want 82K rows in the output? What will the client do with that much data? I ask because if the client will further digest the results, maybe such would be better done in SQL.
[I need a grid in the program developed with Delphi EX8, which displays all the users and then be able to apply filters on the grid with Delphi procedures. "I've always done this, maybe I have to do differently?"]

Comment: Load 82K rows into a program, _then_ do filtering?  Bad design.  Filtering should be done _as you fetch the rows_.  I don't know if Delphi is forcing that, but you should look for a better architecture.  Disk drives and network connections go only so fast.

Comment: Thank you Rick James, now the software is in betatest and works fine without errors, the only bad thing is the performace in user search (81k users for 260K documents = 1.9 sec.). I will use your advice in next software.

Comment: @carmelocony When you have time, please post AFTER 24 hours of uptime, text results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%used%'; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%open%'; for analysis. How many CORES on your host CPU? Post current results of EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (your query); including the QUERY for Suggestions to IMPROVE your host server's response time.

Answer (score 0):

Changing these values in my.ini, in phpmyadmin here is the improved result.

The time it takes to populate the grid in my Delphi application, now 1.9 sec compared to before 2.8 sec.

my pc has 8Gb RAM;

Can I reduce the time to populate the grid in Delphi? Maybe I have to make a new request for this.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
```

BEFORE

```
innodb_log_file_size = 64M
```

(83705 del total, The query employed 1,0000 sec.)

AFTER

```
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
```

(83705 del total, The query employed 0,0000 sec.)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is "grouwise-max", then you left out a clause:

```
select  User.*, Doc.LastDoc
    FROM  de_Users AS Us
    LEFT JOIN  
    (
        SELECT  UserID,MAX(DataFi) AS LastDoc
            FROM  de_doc
            GROUP BY  UserID 
    ) as Doc  ON Doc.UserID = Us.ID_U
             AND Doc.LastDoc = Us.DataFi    -- this was missing
    ORDER BY  Us.Name ASC, Doc.LastDoc DESC;
```

That will also lead to many fewer rows being delivered, hence addressing the performance question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this query and check whether the output is same as your query

```
select Us.*,  max(Doc.DataFi) as LastDoc
FROM de_Users AS Us 
LEFT JOIN de_doc as Doc on Doc.UserID = Us.ID_U
group by Us.ID_U   
ORDER BY Us.Name ASC, LastDoc DESC;
```

Comment: It takes the same amount of time. No improvement.

Comment: Is the output is correct? If so the above query is optimized by removing unwanted sub query inside a join. Now what does the `explain` command shows?

Comment: Using `select Us.*, .... group by Us.ID_U` is generally wrong SQL to write in SQL standard 1992.. But it can be valid in SQL standard 1999+ where there is functioncal dependecy which MySQL 5.7.5+ supports... ***But do not thrust using "functioncal dependecy" in lower MySQL versions then 5.7.5***

Comment: @RaymondNijland Are you denoting that instead of `*` it should be column names?

Comment: *"Are you denoting that instead of * it should be column names?"* Not iam saying this [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) .. Also the topicstarters query is generally the approach which is correct..

Comment: Yeah, Read the doc you have shared, 

Comment: This formulation has the misfortune of hauling around all of `Us.*` , only to collapse out most of it later.  ("explode-implode").